# BitmapImage into Image in xaml. Invisible picture

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1

I have the following code in my application:

```
public AddNewPlace()
    {
        viewModel = new AddNewPlaceViewModel();
        this.InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this.viewModel;
        viewModel.GetUserLocation();
        NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;

        // Attach event which will return the picked files
        var app = Application.Current as App;
        if (app != null)
        {
            app.FilesPicked += OnFilesPicked;
        }   
    }
     private async void OnFilesPicked(IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files)
    {
        Image.Source = null;


        if (files.Count > 0)
        {
            // Check if video or image and pick first file to show
            var imageFile = files.FirstOrDefault(f => SupportedImageFileTypes.Contains(f.FileType.ToLower()));
            if (imageFile != null)
            {
                var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(await imageFile.OpenReadAsync());
                Image.Source = bitmapImage;
            }
        }
    }
    private void BtnFileOpenPickerPhotosClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TriggerPicker(SupportedImageFileTypes);
    }
    private static void TriggerPicker(IEnumerable<string> fileTypeFilers, bool shouldPickMultiple = false)
    {
        var fop = new FileOpenPicker();
        foreach (var fileType in fileTypeFilers)
        {
            fop.FileTypeFilter.Add(fileType);
        }
        if (shouldPickMultiple)
        {
            fop.PickMultipleFilesAndContinue();
        }
        else
        {
            fop.PickSingleFileAndContinue();
        }
    }
```

And this is code from xaml.

```
<Image Grid.Row="5"
       x:Name="Image" 
       Width="192" 
       Height="192"/>
```

When I want to show this choosen image to xaml the image is not visible. There is no errors or warnings. Any idea how to fix it? Maybe I need a converter? but I do not know how to use it...

Comment: Can you provide the whole code? where is your `if`?

Comment: It works for me. We'll need to see more code. Are you *sure* that the if condition is being met?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28099678/mvvm-image-bind-source-from-fileopenpicker    <----question is there