# MVVM: Image Bind Source from FileOpenPicker

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1

I added the OnActivated() into app.xaml.cs it is work correctly:

```
protected async override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
        {
            var continuationEventArgs = args as IContinuationActivatedEventArgs;
            if (continuationEventArgs != null)
            {
                switch (continuationEventArgs.Kind)
                {
                    case ActivationKind.PickFileContinuation:
                        FileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs arguments = continuationEventArgs as FileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs;
                        string passedData = (string)arguments.ContinuationData["keyParameter"];
                        StorageFile file = arguments.Files.FirstOrDefault(); // your picked file
                        addNewPlaceViewModel.OnFilesPicked(file);
                        // do what you want
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

I hooked already FileOpenPicker into MVVM project correctly. This is my code:

```
private static readonly IEnumerable<string> SupportedImageFileTypes = new List<string> { ".jpeg", ".jpg", ".png" };
    public AddNewPlaceViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        this.navigationService = navigationService;
    }
    private async void OnFilesPicked(IStorageFile file)
    {

            if (file != null)
            {
                var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(await file.OpenReadAsync());
                Picture = bitmapImage;
                //IN debugger in picture I have sht but in xaml i cannot show this.
            }
        }
    }
    private static void TriggerPicker(IEnumerable<string> fileTypeFilers, bool shouldPickMultiple = false)
    {
        var fop = new FileOpenPicker();
        foreach (var fileType in fileTypeFilers)
        {
            fop.FileTypeFilter.Add(fileType);
        }
        if (shouldPickMultiple)
        {
            fop.PickMultipleFilesAndContinue();
        }
        else
        {
            fop.PickSingleFileAndContinue();
        }
    }
```

This is situation after `Picture = bitmapImage;`[image]
I have also set up Binding and ICommand:

```
public ICommand UpdatePictureCommand
        {
            get { return new RelayCommand(o => TriggerPicker(SupportedImageFileTypes)); }
        }
private ImageSource _Picture;
        public ImageSource Picture
        {
            get
            {
                return _Picture;
            }
            set
            {
                _Picture = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Picture");
            }
        }
```

And this is my XAML in pivot item(button and Image) when I want to show photo which I have taken.

```
<Button Grid.Row ="4" 
                    Content="Dodaj zdjęcie" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    Command="{Binding UpdatePictureCommand}"/>
<Image Grid.Row="6"
                Width="192" 
                Height="192" 
                Source="{Binding Picture, Mode=TwoWay}"
                />
```

A file open picker is working correctly(I can choose or take a photo) but after that I cannot see choosed/taked photo in my XAML. What is going wrong with that code?

Comment: When and how `OnFilesPicked` is fired? Also what is Image is it a valid name of your control?

Comment: Are you somehow [using OnActivated event](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25011329/2681948), hence you are using `..AndContinue()`?

Comment: I updated the code. I think it is wrong that I have OnFilesPicked() in viewmodel.

Comment: I want to do what you have done in that link. But I want to do this in MVVM in ViewModel and bind image to view.

Comment: Take a look [at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn631755.aspx) and implementation of interfece *IContiuable...* - maybe you can make use of it in your Page/ViewModel and then fire your OnFilesPicked method with passed arguments from OnActiveted event.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a converter something like this

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(Image), typeof(System.Windows.Media.ImageSource))]
    public class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            var bitmap = (Bitmap)value;

            return System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                bitmap.GetHbitmap(),
                IntPtr.Zero,
                Int32Rect.Empty,
                BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
        }


        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Okey, but where I have to create that converter...I build app in mvvm and can I have fileopenpicker in behind code?

Comment: Can you say something about new situation?